# HAProxy ACLs: Match any stub for one backend but if stub not provided, match a different backend

Tags: haproxy

This has been driving me crazy.  I'd like HAProxy to use two different backends based on the following FQDNs given:

**Backend 1:** http or https **+** any stub domain **+** example.org **+** any port or path (if given)

**Backend 2:** http or https **+** example.org **+** any port or path (if given)

*Examples:*

| Backend 1 | http://taco.example.org/path or https://sandwich.example.org/path |

| Backend 2 | http://example.org/path or https://example.org/path |

Here is what I am currently doing which doesn't work:

```
acl stub_domain hdr_reg(host) -i [^\.]+\.example\.org(.*)
use_backend backend1 if stub_domain
default_backend backend2
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!  The mode was set to tcp and not http.  The ACLs work now.  Thanks!